# MySQL Adding external space for storage tables

Tags: mysql, ftp, innodb, sshfs

I would like to add more freespace to storage mysql tables.

I have tried use symbolic links with curlftpfs/sshfs (first create table, then move to ftp and add ln -s) but mysql gives me error  "Operating system error number 95 in a file operation." on start.

I have VPS and FTP server (with SSH access), I would like connect remotely FTP space to my VPS which will be used to store ibd data.

Data tables must be store only on external server, not on VPS.
I am using InnoDB engine, 5.5.50 Mariadb, centos 7.

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I would ask in the dba forum

Answer (score 0):

Choice 1:  Bigger disk drive.  Some OSs allow dynamic addition of drives to add space.

Choice 2:  If the OS can see another drive, you *may* be able to ask MySQL to put certain *files* on that drive.

No, you cannot use FTP or other "remote" mechanisms.